# Filtering of maximum value by ID and category sum

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task that is quite simple: I need to get the sum of values in the categories of each ID, and keep the category with the highest sum:

```
id    category   value
1       A         10 
1       A         15
1       B         13
2       A         80
```

So, in this case the sum of `value` for each category-id pair would be:

```
id    category   value
1       A         25 
1       B         13
2       A         80
```

And then the maximum for `id` == 1 is 25 and for the other is 80, so the final dataframe is:

```
id    category   value
1       A         25 
2       A         80
```

I achieved this like this:

```
(df.groupby(['id', 'category'])['value']
 .sum().reset_index().sort_values(by=['id', 'value'])
 .drop_duplicates(['id'], keep='last'))
```

I feel this can be done in lesser steps, maybe with some transform, but I can't find a better way. Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the following. Compute the first grouping by id and category, sum up the values:

```
y = df.groupby(["id","category"])["value"].sum()
```

Afterwards, grab the best category according to your definition:

```
y.groupby("category").sum().nlargest(1)
```

Combining these, so that we get the full job done:

```
y = df.groupby(["id","category"])["value"].sum()
cat = y.groupby("category").sum().nlargest(1).index
y.loc[:,cat]
```

Comment: I believe the original target was a max-sum category *per id*, rather than a single category overall? So `y.loc[y.groupby('id').idxmax()]`